# Data overwritting issue with Telegraf MQTT in InfluxDB

Tags: mqtt, influxdb, telegraf

Telegraf MQTT plugin in InfluxDB is overwriting data with same `_field`.

I am recieving the following input data via Telegraf MQTT in InfluxDB `[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]`. The issue I am facing is that MQTT is overwriting the `Latitude` and `Longitude` values. Instead of displaying all three object values in InfluxDB. I can only see last object value and rest are overwritten.

Input data:

```
[
{“Latitude”:48.8108060, “Longitude”:13.5473266},
{“Latitude”:48.8103460, “Longitude”:13.5481769},
{“Latitude”:48.8070218, “Longitude”:13.5567778}
]
```

To address the above issue I want to process the incoming data and convert the input data to the processed data below:

```
[
{“wp1”: {“Latitude”:48.8108060, “Longitude”:13.5473266}},
{“wp2”:{“Latitude”:48.8103460, “Longitude”:13.5481769}},
{“wp3”:{“Latitude”:48.8070218, “Longitude”:13.5567778}}
]
```

With the above processed data I can see all three JSON objects in the database as the `_field` is different.

How can I achieve this task?